# How to test internal members of solidity library or contract in brownie?

Tags: solidity, brownie

Say I have the following `SimpleMath` solidity `library` defined as follows:

```
library SimpleMath {

  function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns(uint)
  {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

How do I import this `library` using brownie in my python script and call the `add` method? I would like to run unit tests of `library` functions.

I don't seem to have an issue importing the library, however I can't access its functions even when changing the access modifier to public I get the following brownie error:

```py
from brownie import SimpleMath

def test_add():
  retVal = SimpleMath.add(10, 20)
  assert retVal == 30
```

> AttributeError: 'ContractContainer' object has no attribute 'add'

Edit: So apparently you have to deploy a `library` the same way you would deploy a contract and then access it's methods, however I can't access the library's `internal` methods only `external`/`public`:

```py
simpleMath = SimpleMath.deploy({'from': account})
simpleMath = simpleMath.add() # since add is internal cannot access
```

> AttributeError: Contract 'SimpleMath' object has no attribute 'add'

How then can I test a libraries functions that are internal in brownie?

Comment: Import it where? Is it in another file?

Comment: Hi Patrick, yes the same way I would import a contract called SimpleStorage in my python script and call it's methods.

Comment: If you are using hardhat, you can try `hardhat-exposed`. Although I haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't access `internal` or `private` functions externally for both contracts and libraries I wrapped the method/s of the `library` `SimpleMath` in the method/s of a `contract` called `TestSimpleMath`, which has it's methods set to `external`, thus exposing the library method/s.

```
import { SimpleMath } from '.SimpleMath.sol';

contract TestSimpleMath {
  function add(uint a, uint b) external pure returns(uint) {
    return SimpleMath.add(a, b);
  }
}
```